# Wrong $index after order by in Angular

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

Have some problem after ordering items in ng-repeat. After click on item open page with wrong index.
My example HTML code, open page correct:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="showPost($index)">{{item.title}}</div>
```

If add orderby, show wrong post index:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'-title'" ng-click="showPost($index)">{{item.title}}</div>
```

And my $scope function showPost():

```
  $scope.showPost = function(index){
    $rootScope.postContent = $scope.catItems[index];
    $scope.ons.navigator.pushPage('post.html');
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is that the order of the array in the ngRepeat (after applying the orderBy filter) is different than the order of $scope.catItems.

It's better to fix the code by passing the object itself as a function parameter and finding the object in the array instead of passing an index.
Assuming $scope.items and $scope.catItems are different arrays, try something like that:

```
// HTML
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'-title'" ng-click="showPost(item)">{{item.title}}</div>
// JS

$scope.showPost = function(item){
    var index = $scope.items.indexOf(item);
    $rootScope.postContent = $scope.catItems[index];
    $scope.ons.navigator.pushPage('post.html');
  };
```